Win32Exception: A required privilege is not held by the client when accessing Control Panel items in Sitecore
I am currently working on a Sitecore instance 10.4 and this is vanilla instance and encountering an issue when trying to access any Control Panel item. Whenever I click on any of the items, I receive the following error:
Server Error in '/' Application. A required privilege is not held by
the client


System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A required privilege is not held by the client
Microsoft.Win32.NativeMethods.CreateDirectory(String path, SafeLocalMemHandle acl) +142
System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.CreateTempDirectoryWithAce(String directory, String identity) +90
System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.GetTempFileName(String tempDir) +247
System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.EnsureTempNameCreated() +98
System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.AddExtension(String fileExtension, Boolean keepFile) +35



Did you checked this https://kb.msp360.com/standalone-backup/general/a-required-privilege-is-not-held-by-client#:~:text=Cause,access%20to%20the%20Windows%20installation...Seems related to it. Can you check once.

This error means your account doesn't have enough permissions to do what the program is trying to do. This usually happens when trying to create new folders or files.
Here I'm adding some steps to Fix This Sitecore Problem:
1. Check Permissions

Make sure the Sitecore user can access and edit important folders like \temp and \App_Data


Check if the user is allowed to run background tasks

2. Check IIS Settings

If you're using a special user account, make sure it has the right permissions
Try switching to "Local System" temporarily to test if that fixes it

3. Look at Temporary File Settings

Check where Sitecore is trying to save temporary files


Make sure those locations aren't blocked


You can change where files are saved if needed

4. Check Windows Security

Look at your Windows security settings


Make sure your account has basic rights to create and manage files

5. Check Your Antivirus

Your antivirus might be blocking file creation


Try turning it off briefly to test if that's the problem

6. Restart Things

After making changes, restart IIS or refresh the system to make sure everything takes effect

Hope it will help.

Point 2 is working, Thanks Abhishek.

The error points to issues with creating temporary files or directories. Ensure that the App Pool identity running the Sitecore instance has the appropriate permissions to write to the Windows temp folder (C:\Windows\Temp) or the ASP.NET temp folder (C:\Users\<AppPoolUser>\AppData\Local\Temp).
Grant Modify permissions to the application pool identity for these directories.
Another side is to check if some security software can block file operations, especially in temp folders. Check if any antivirus or security policies are blocking file creation in the directories mentioned
Hope this will help.

Check the local sitecore instance folder, go to permissions -> security, and give full control permissions to IIS_User and reload.
